# Show Label text (country name) on Google FusionTablesLayer

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am adding a fusionTableLayer on google table by Google Fusion table.
But It not showing the country name (Label text). Country name is hide behind layer.

How to show country name (Label text) on Layer.

Like in this map we can't see name of UK/France/India/Turkey

[image: google-fusion-tables fusion-table-layer Style]

JS code:

```
function initialize() {
  var world_center = new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: world_center,
    zoom: 3,
    scrollwheel: true,
  });

  var style = [
    {
      "featureType" : "landscape",
      "elementType" : "geometry",
      "stylers" : [{"color" : "#7F7F7F"}]
    },
    {
      "featureType" : "all",
      "elementType" : "labels",
      // "stylers" : [{"visibility" : "off"}]
    },
    {
      "featureType" : "all",
      "elementType" : "labels.icon",
      "stylers" : [{"visibility" : "off"}]
    },
    {
      "featureType" : "landscape",
      "elementType" : "labels",
      "stylers" : [{"visibility" : "off"}]
    },
    {
      "featureType" : "poi",
      "stylers" : [{"visibility" : "off"}]
    },
    {
      "featureType" : "road",
      "stylers" : [{"visibility" : "off"}]
    }
  ];

  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
    map: map,
    name: 'Styled Map'
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   query: {
     select: "name, id, gemo, location_type",
     from: table_id
   },
   options : {suppressInfoWindows:true},
   styleId:1,
   clickable:false
  });
  layer.setMap(map);

}
```

On **styleId 1** of fusion table.

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#styleSetting",
 "tableId": "1IbTyJDdJfQXFFmVr_5E95MQiIApiGLhkaC4ohzDM",
 "styleId": 1,
 "polygonOptions": {
  "strokeColor": "#666666",
  "strokeOpacity": 0,
  "strokeWeight": 0,
  "fillColorStyler": {
   "kind": "fusiontables#buckets",
   "columnName": "style_14",
   "buckets": [
    {
     "min": 143.5,
     "max": 144.5,
     "color": "#098d71",
     "opacity": 1
    },
    {
     "min": 144.5,
     "max": 145.5,
     "color": "#92d050",
     "opacity": 1
    },
    {
     "min": 145.5,
     "max": 146.5,
     "color": "#ebe8cf",
     "opacity": 1
    },
    {
     "min": 146.5,
     "max": 147.6,
     "color": "#cec660",
     "opacity": 1
    },
    {
     "min": 147.5,
     "max": 148.5,
     "color": "#c06e36",
     "opacity": 1
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hide all the country names on the map tiles, add your own labels on top of the FusionTablesLayer.

Comment: @geocodezip , Thanks for quick response.How to add Text Label on the top of the fusion table?

Comment: [Here is an example that adds zip code labels over a FusionTableLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html)

Answer (score 2):

One option:  use [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox) as a label. ([original google code link](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html), googlecode was turned off by google)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9o05cbh/5/) (needs some tuning with the smaller countries, maybe use a [MarkerManager](http://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markermanager/examples/google_northamerica_offices.html) to control the zoom levels they appear at)

**code snippet:**

```js
var table_id = "1IbTyJDdJfQXFFmVr_5E95MQiIApiGLhkaC4ohzDM";
var labels = [];

function initialize() {
    var world_center = new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: world_center,
        zoom: 3,
        minZoom: 2,
        scrollwheel: true,
        styles: style
    });

    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
        map: map,
        name: 'Styled Map'
    });

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: "name, id, gemo, location_type",
            from: table_id
        },
        options: {
            suppressInfoWindows: true
        },
        styleId: 1,
        clickable: false
    });
    layer.setMap(map);
    for (var i=0; i < countriesJson.length; i++) {
    labels.push(new InfoBox({
  content: countriesJson[i].name
 ,boxStyle: {
    border: "none"
   ,textAlign: "center"
          ,backgroundColor:"none"
   ,fontSize: "8pt"
   ,width: "50px"
  }
 ,disableAutoPan: true
 ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, 0)
 ,position: new google.maps.LatLng(
        countriesJson[i].lat,countriesJson[i].lng)
 ,closeBoxURL: ""
 ,isHidden: false
 ,enableEventPropagation: true
      }));
      labels[labels.length-1].open(map);
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var style = [{
        "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
            "color": "#7F7F7F"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }];

var countriesJson = [{name:  "Afghanistan", lat:33.93911, lng:67.709953},
{name:  "Albania", lat:41.153332, lng:20.168331},
{name:  "Algeria", lat:28.033886, lng:1.659626},
{name:  "American Samoa", lat:-14.30602, lng:-170.696181},
{name:  "Andorra", lat:42.506285, lng:1.521801},
{name:  "Angola", lat:-11.202692, lng:17.873887},
{name:  "Anguilla", lat:18.220554, lng:-63.068615},
{name:  "Antigua and Barbuda", lat:17.060816, lng:-61.796428},
{name:  "Argentina", lat:-38.416097, lng:-63.616672},
{name:  "Armenia", lat:40.069099, lng:45.038189},
{name:  "Aruba", lat:12.52111, lng:-69.968338},
{name:  "Australia", lat:-25.274398, lng:133.775136},
{name:  "Austria", lat:47.516231, lng:14.550072},
{name:  "Azerbaijan", lat:40.143105, lng:47.576927},
{name:  "The Bahamas", lat:25.03428, lng:-77.39628},
{name:  "Bahrain", lat:26.0667, lng:50.5577},
{name:  "Bangladesh", lat:23.684994, lng:90.356331},
{name:  "Barbados", lat:13.193887, lng:-59.543198},
{name:  "Belarus", lat:53.709807, lng:27.953389},
{name:  "Belgium", lat:50.503887, lng:4.469936},
{name:  "Belize", lat:17.189877, lng:-88.49765},
{name:  "Benin", lat:9.30769, lng:2.315834},
{name:  "Bermuda", lat:32.3078, lng:-64.7505},
{name:  "Bhutan", lat:27.514162, lng:90.433601},
{name:  "Bolivia", lat:-16.290154, lng:-63.588653},
{name:  "Bosnia and Herzegovina", lat:43.915886, lng:17.679076},
{name:  "Botswana", lat:-22.328474, lng:24.684866},
{name:  "Bouvet Island", lat:-54.423199, lng:3.413194},
{name:  "Brazil", lat:-14.235004, lng:-51.92528},
{name:  "British Indian Ocean Territory", lat:-7.334623, lng:72.424251},
{name:  "Brunei", lat:4.535277, lng:114.727669},
{name:  "Bulgaria", lat:42.733883, lng:25.48583},
{name:  "Burkina Faso", lat:12.238333, lng:-1.561593},
{name:  "Burundi", lat:-3.373056, lng:29.918886},
{name:  "Cambodia", lat:12.565679, lng:104.990963},
{name:  "Cameroon", lat:7.369722, lng:12.354722},
{name:  "Canada", lat:56.130366, lng:-106.346771},
{name:  "Cape Verde", lat:15.120142, lng:-23.605172},
{name:  "Cayman Islands", lat:19.3133, lng:-81.2546},
{name:  "Central African Republic", lat:6.611111, lng:20.939444},
{name:  "Chad", lat:15.454166, lng:18.732207},
{name:  "Chile", lat:-35.675147, lng:-71.542969},
{name:  "China", lat:35.86166, lng:104.195397},
{name:  "Christmas Island", lat:-10.447525, lng:105.690449},
{name:  "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", lat:-12.170874, lng:96.841739},
{name:  "Colombia", lat:4.570868, lng:-74.297333},
{name:  "Comoros", lat:-11.6455, lng:43.3333},
{name:  "Republic of the Congo", lat:-0.228021, lng:15.827659},
{name:  "Democratic Republic of the Congo", lat:-4.038333, lng:21.758664},
{name:  "Cook Islands", lat:-21.236736, lng:-159.777671},
{name:  "Costa Rica", lat:9.748917, lng:-83.753428},
{name:  "Côte d'Ivoire", lat:7.539989, lng:-5.54708},
{name:  "Croatia", lat:45.1, lng:15.2},
{name:  "Cuba", lat:21.521757, lng:-77.781167},
{name:  "Cyprus", lat:35.126413, lng:33.429859},
{name:  "Czech Republic", lat:49.817492, lng:15.472962},
{name:  "Denmark", lat:56.26392, lng:9.501785},
{name:  "Djibouti", lat:11.825138, lng:42.590275},
{name:  "Dominica", lat:15.414999, lng:-61.370976},
{name:  "Dominican Republic", lat:18.735693, lng:-70.162651},
{name:  "Ecuador", lat:-1.831239, lng:-78.183406},
{name:  "Egypt", lat:26.820553, lng:30.802498},
{name:  "El Salvador", lat:13.794185, lng:-88.89653},
{name:  "Equatorial Guinea", lat:1.650801, lng:10.267895},
{name:  "Eritrea", lat:15.179384, lng:39.782334},
{name:  "Estonia", lat:58.595272, lng:25.013607},
{name:  "Ethiopia", lat:9.145, lng:40.489673},
{name:  "FIQQ 1ZZ, Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)", lat:-51.796253, lng:-59.523613},
{name:  "Faroe Islands", lat:61.892635, lng:-6.911806},
{name:  "Fiji", lat:-17.713371, lng:178.065032},
{name:  "Finland", lat:61.92411, lng:25.748151},
{name:  "France", lat:46.227638, lng:2.213749},
{name:  "French Guiana", lat:3.933889, lng:-53.125782},
{name:  "French Polynesia", lat:-17.679742, lng:-149.406843},
{name:  "French Southern and Antarctic Lands", lat:-49.280366, lng:69.348557},
{name:  "Gabon", lat:-0.803689, lng:11.609444},
{name:  "The Gambia", lat:13.443182, lng:-15.310139},
{name:  "Georgia", lat:42.315407, lng:43.356892},
{name:  "Germany", lat:51.165691, lng:10.451526},
{name:  "Ghana", lat:7.946527, lng:-1.023194},
{name:  "Gibraltar", lat:36.140751, lng:-5.353585},
{name:  "Greece", lat:39.074208, lng:21.824312},
{name:  "Greenland", lat:71.706936, lng:-42.604303},
{name:  "Grenada", lat:12.1165, lng:-61.679},
{name:  "Guadeloupe", lat:16.265, lng:-61.551},
{name:  "Guam", lat:13.444304, lng:144.793731},
{name:  "Guatemala", lat:15.783471, lng:-90.230759},
{name:  "Guinea", lat:9.945587, lng:-9.696645},
{name:  "Guyana", lat:4.860416, lng:-58.93018},
{name:  "Haiti", lat:18.971187, lng:-72.285215},
{name:  "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", lat:-53.08181, lng:73.504158},
{name:  "Honduras", lat:15.199999, lng:-86.241905},
{name:  "Hong Kong", lat:22.396428, lng:114.109497},
{name:  "Hungary", lat:47.162494, lng:19.503304},
{name:  "Iceland", lat:64.963051, lng:-19.020835},
{name:  "India", lat:20.593684, lng:78.96288},
{name:  "Indonesia", lat:-0.789275, lng:113.921327},
{name:  "Iran", lat:32.427908, lng:53.688046},
{name:  "Iraq", lat:33.223191, lng:43.679291},
{name:  "Ireland", lat:53.41291, lng:-8.24389},
{name:  "Israel", lat:31.046051, lng:34.851612},
{name:  "Italy", lat:41.87194, lng:12.56738},
{name:  "Jamaica", lat:18.109581, lng:-77.297508},
{name:  "Japan", lat:36.204824, lng:138.252924},
{name:  "Jordan", lat:30.585164, lng:36.238414},
{name:  "Kazakhstan", lat:48.019573, lng:66.923684},
{name:  "Kenya", lat:-0.023559, lng:37.906193},
{name:  "Kiribati", lat:1.870883, lng:-157.363026},
{name:  "North Korea", lat:40.339852, lng:127.510093},
{name:  "South Korea", lat:35.907757, lng:127.766922},
{name:  "Kuwait", lat:29.31166, lng:47.481766},
{name:  "Kyrgyzstan", lat:41.20438, lng:74.766098},
{name:  "Laos", lat:19.85627, lng:102.495496},
{name:  "Latvia", lat:56.879635, lng:24.603189},
{name:  "Lebanon", lat:33.854721, lng:35.862285},
{name:  "Lesotho", lat:-29.609988, lng:28.233608},
{name:  "Liberia", lat:6.428055, lng:-9.429499},
{name:  "Libya", lat:26.3351, lng:17.228331},
{name:  "Liechtenstein", lat:47.166, lng:9.555373},
{name:  "Lithuania", lat:55.169438, lng:23.881275},
{name:  "Luxembourg", lat:49.815273, lng:6.129583},
{name:  "Macau", lat:22.198745, lng:113.543873},
{name:  "Macedonia (FYROM)", lat:41.608635, lng:21.745275},
{name:  "Madagascar", lat:-18.766947, lng:46.869107},
{name:  "Malawi", lat:-13.254308, lng:34.301525},
{name:  "Malawi", lat:-13.254308, lng:34.301525},
{name:  "Malaysia", lat:4.210484, lng:101.975766},
{name:  "Maldives", lat:1.977247, lng:73.536103},
{name:  "Mali", lat:17.570692, lng:-3.996166},
{name:  "Malta", lat:35.937496, lng:14.375416},
{name:  "Marshall Islands", lat:6.068394, lng:171.989379},
{name:  "Martinique", lat:14.641528, lng:-61.024174},
{name:  "Mauritania", lat:21.00789, lng:-10.940835},
{name:  "Mauritius", lat:-20.348404, lng:57.552152},
{name:  "Mayotte", lat:-12.8275, lng:45.166244},
{name:  "Mexico", lat:23.634501, lng:-102.552784},
{name:  "Federated States of Micronesia", lat:6.887481, lng:158.215072},
{name:  "Moldova", lat:47.411631, lng:28.369885},
{name:  "Monaco", lat:43.738418, lng:7.424616},
{name:  "Mongolia", lat:46.862496, lng:103.846656},
{name:  "Montserrat", lat:16.742498, lng:-62.187366},
{name:  "Montenegro", lat:42.708678, lng:19.37439},
{name:  "Morocco", lat:31.791702, lng:-7.09262},
{name:  "Mozambique", lat:-18.665695, lng:35.529562},
{name:  "Myanmar (Burma)", lat:21.913965, lng:95.956223},
{name:  "Namibia", lat:-22.95764, lng:18.49041},
{name:  "Nauru", lat:-0.522778, lng:166.931503},
{name:  "Nepal", lat:28.394857, lng:84.124008},
{name:  "Netherlands", lat:52.132633, lng:5.291266},
{name:  "Netherlands Antilles", lat:12.20189, lng:-68.262382},
{name:  "New Caledonia", lat:-20.904305, lng:165.618042},
{name:  "New Zealand", lat:-40.900557, lng:174.885971},
{name:  "Nicaragua", lat:12.865416, lng:-85.207229},
{name:  "Niger", lat:17.607789, lng:8.081666},
{name:  "Nigeria", lat:9.081999, lng:8.675277},
{name:  "Niue", lat:-19.054445, lng:-169.867233},
{name:  "Norfolk Island", lat:-29.040835, lng:167.954712},
{name:  "Northern Mariana Islands", lat:15.0979, lng:145.6739},
{name:  "Norway", lat:60.472024, lng:8.468946},
{name:  "Oman", lat:21.512583, lng:55.923255},
{name:  "Pakistan", lat:30.375321, lng:69.345116},
{name:  "Palau", lat:7.51498, lng:134.58252},
{name:  "Palestine", lat:31.952162, lng:35.233154},
{name:  "Panama", lat:8.537981, lng:-80.782127},
{name:  "Papua New Guinea", lat:-6.314993, lng:143.95555},
{name:  "Paraguay", lat:-23.442503, lng:-58.443832},
{name:  "Peru", lat:-9.189967, lng:-75.015152},
{name:  "Philippines", lat:12.879721, lng:121.774017},
{name:  "Pitcairn Islands", lat:-24.376745, lng:-128.324235},
{name:  "Poland", lat:51.919438, lng:19.145136},
{name:  "Portugal", lat:39.399872, lng:-8.224454},
{name:  "Puerto Rico", lat:18.220833, lng:-66.590149},
{name:  "Qatar", lat:25.354826, lng:51.183884},
{name:  "Reunion", lat:-21.115141, lng:55.536384},
{name:  "Romania", lat:45.943161, lng:24.96676},
{name:  "Russia", lat:61.52401, lng:105.318756},
{name:  "Rwanda", lat:-1.940278, lng:29.873888},
{name:  "Rwanda", lat:-1.940278, lng:29.873888},
{name:  "Saint Helena", lat:-15.965528, lng:-5.711485},
{name:  "Saint Kitts and Nevis", lat:17.357822, lng:-62.782998},
{name:  "Saint Lucia", lat:13.909444, lng:-60.978893},
{name:  "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", lat:46.8852, lng:-56.3159},
{name:  "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", lat:13.252818, lng:-61.197163},
{name:  "Samoa", lat:-13.759029, lng:-172.104629},
{name:  "San Marino", lat:43.94236, lng:12.457777},
{name:  "São Tomé and Príncipe", lat:0.18636, lng:6.613081},
{name:  "Saudi Arabia", lat:23.885942, lng:45.079162},
{name:  "Senegal", lat:14.497401, lng:-14.452362},
{name:  "Serbia", lat:44.016521, lng:21.005859},
{name:  "Seychelles", lat:-4.679574, lng:55.491977},
{name:  "Sierra Leone", lat:8.460555, lng:-11.779889},
{name:  "Singapore", lat:1.352083, lng:103.819836},
{name:  "Slovakia", lat:48.669026, lng:19.699024},
{name:  "Slovenia", lat:46.151241, lng:14.995463},
{name:  "Solomon Islands", lat:-9.64571, lng:160.156194},
{name:  "Somalia", lat:5.152149, lng:46.199616},
{name:  "South Africa", lat:-30.559482, lng:22.937506},
{name:  "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", lat:-54.429579, lng:-36.587909},
{name:  "Spain", lat:40.463667, lng:-3.74922},
{name:  "Sri Lanka", lat:7.873054, lng:80.771797},
{name:  "Sudan", lat:12.862807, lng:30.217636},
{name:  "Suriname", lat:3.919305, lng:-56.027783},
{name:  "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", lat:77.553604, lng:23.670272},
{name:  "Swaziland", lat:-26.522503, lng:31.465866},
{name:  "Sweden", lat:60.128161, lng:18.643501},
{name:  "Switzerland", lat:46.818188, lng:8.227512},
{name:  "Syria", lat:34.802075, lng:38.996815},
{name:  "Taiwan", lat:23.69781, lng:120.960515},
{name:  "Tajikistan", lat:38.861034, lng:71.276093},
{name:  "Tanzania", lat:-6.369028, lng:34.888822},
{name:  "Thailand", lat:15.870032, lng:100.992541},
{name:  "Timor-Leste", lat:-8.874217, lng:125.727539},
{name:  "Togo", lat:8.619543, lng:0.824782},
{name:  "Tokelau", lat:-9.2002, lng:-171.8484},
{name:  "Tonga", lat:-21.178986, lng:-175.198242},
{name:  "Trinidad and Tobago", lat:10.691803, lng:-61.222503},
{name:  "Tunisia", lat:33.886917, lng:9.537499},
{name:  "Turkey", lat:38.963745, lng:35.243322},
{name:  "Turkmenistan", lat:38.969719, lng:59.556278},
{name:  "Turks and Caicos Islands", lat:21.694025, lng:-71.797928},
{name:  "Tuvalu", lat:-7.478442, lng:178.679921},
{name:  "Uganda", lat:1.373333, lng:32.290275},
{name:  "Ukraine", lat:48.379433, lng:31.16558},
{name:  "United Arab Emirates", lat:23.424076, lng:53.847818},
{name:  "United Kingdom", lat:55.378051, lng:-3.435973},
{name:  "United States", lat:37.09024, lng:-95.712891},
{name:  "Uruguay", lat:-32.522779, lng:-55.765835},
{name:  "Uzbekistan", lat:41.377491, lng:64.585262},
{name:  "Vanuatu", lat:-15.376706, lng:166.959158},
{name:  "Venezuela", lat:6.42375, lng:-66.58973},
{name:  "Vietnam", lat:14.058324, lng:108.277199},
{name:  "British Virgin Islands", lat:18.420695, lng:-64.639968},
{name:  "U.S. Virgin Islands", lat:18.335765, lng:-64.896335},
{name:  "Wallis and Futuna", lat:-14.2938, lng:-178.1165},
{name:  "Western Sahara", lat:24.215527, lng:-12.885834},
{name:  "Yemen", lat:15.552727, lng:48.516388},
{name:  "Zambia", lat:-13.133897, lng:27.849332},
{name:  "Zimbabwe", lat:-19.015438, lng:29.154857}];
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```